# travel restriction exemption from India to the US on an F1 visa

Tags: usa, india, f1-visas, covid-19

Because of the high covid case loads in India the US announced travel restrictions between the US ad India. There appear to be exemptions to these restrictions for students on an F1 visa.

It is not clear if this exemption applies immediately, or one month before the start of the fall semester. United airlines support staff says that I may travel, however the international students services organization at my university says that I likely won't b able to travel.

Which one is true? Where can I find a source that clarifies this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [an exemption](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/national-interest-exceptions-for-certain-travelers-from-china-Iran-brazil-south-africa-schengen-area-united-kingdom-and-ireland.html) to all the country-based entry bans ([also applying](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/presidential-proclamation-on-the-suspension-of-entry-as-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-coronavirus-disease-2019.html) to the one for India) for F-1 and M-1 students starting a program beginning August 1, 2021 or later. As is usual with F-1 and M-1 students, they can enter up to 30 days before the beginning the their program.

(There was an [earlier exemption](https://web.archive.org/web/20210413200808/https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/national-interest-exceptions-from-certain-travelers-from-the-schengen-area-uk-and-ireland.html) for F-1 and M-1 students for the bans on the Schengen Area, the UK, and Ireland only, without restriction on the program start date. I am not sure why information on that is not available anymore. In any case, it would not help you since you are subject to the India ban.)

Comment: Can you please address my concern here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163802/travel-restriction-to-usa-from-india-for-a-phd-student-with-f1-visa